# How can i reveal the original html() of paragraph on click of "read more" chevron

Tags: jquery, laravel

[This is a screenshot of my screen before the click event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8JTY.png)i am trying to reveal the original contents of a paragraph whose text() i truncated.
I have about three of this paragraph and each has a chevron-down icon which when clicked is supposed to trigger the original html() of the paragraph to be displayed.

The problem is; each time i click any of the chevrons in any of the paragraphs it displays the original html() of the first paragraph.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message').each(function(index) {
    var these = $(this);
    var msg = $(this).html();
    if (msg.length > 250) {
      var new_msg = msg;
      var msg2 = msg.substring(0, 300);
      $(this).html(msg2).append('......');
      $(this).append(" <p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size drop'> <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='normal-link success-link continue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> </a> </p>");
      $(this).find('.drop').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
      $(this).html(msg);
    }

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ticket-box', function() {
      $(this).find('.drop').css({
        opacity: 0.0,
        visibility: "visible"
      }).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
      }, 500);
    }).on('mouseleave', '.ticket-box', function() {
      $(this).find('.drop').css({
        opacity: 1.0,
        visibility: "visible"
      }).animate({
        opacity: 0.0
      }, 200);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.continue', function() {
      $(this).closest('.message').html(new_msg).append("<p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size'> <a class='normal-link delete-link discontinue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> </a> </p>");
      $(this).closest('.message').append("<p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size'> <a class='normal-link delete-link discontinue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> </a> </p>");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.discontinue', function() {
      $(this).closest('.message').html(msg2).append('......').append(" <p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size drop'> <a class='normal-link success-link continue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> </a> </p>");
      $(this).find('.drop').css('visibility', 'hidden');

      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ticket-box', function() {
        $(this).find('.drop').css({
          opacity: 0.0,
          visibility: "visible"
        }).animate({
          opacity: 1.0
        }, 500);
      }).on('mouseleave', '.ticket-box', function() {
        $(this).find('.drop').css({
          opacity: 1.0,
          visibility: "visible"
        }).animate({
          opacity: 0.0
        }, 200);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h4 class="text-left grey x2-margin-left no-margin-top x2-margin-bottom bolder"> 
    {{ strtoupper($ticket_response->created_at) }} 
</h4> 
<?php $messageResponse = nl2br($ticket_response->ticket_response->pluck('message')[$count]) ?> 
<p class="grey x14-font-size text-left x2-margin-left x4-margin-right message no-margin-bottom no-padding letters"> 
   {!! $messageResponse !!} 
</p>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML as well, preferably as a [MCVE]

Comment: Don't add code in comments [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56212625/edit) your question. It would also be better to add an example with rendered html, so the example is complete and verifiable.

Comment: You may want to insert a runnable code snippet using [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), or alternatively another code playground service like jsfiddle to make it picture clear what you're trying to go for.

Comment: You haven't added HTML, you added PHP/laravel. we can't test or replicate the issues with this. Please add the HTML as rendered to the browser. Please give us enough code to replicate the problem, but not too much so the problem does not get lost in clutter. For example `$('.message')` is not represented in the HTML/PHP you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is you are creating an event handler for **all** chevrons on the messages with each message. Assign the event handlers once, after the `each` function. This also had the effect of making `msg` behave more like an array which is why you were always getting the first message.

Store the content and truncated content as [Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) against the message element. You get then retrieve these as required in the click handlers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message').each(function(index) {
    var these = $(this);
    var msg = $(this).html();
    if (msg.length > 250) {
      var new_msg = msg;
      var msg2 = msg.substring(0, 300);
      $(this).html(msg2).append('......');
      $(this).append(" <p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size drop'> <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='normal-link success-link continue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i></a> </p>");
      /*$(this).find('.drop').css('visibility', 'hidden');*/
      //Set Data Attrubutes for source and truncated
      $(this).data("source", msg);
      $(this).data("truncated", msg2);
    } else {
      $(this).html(msg);
    }
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.continue', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').html($(this).closest('.message').data("source")).append("<p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size'> <a class='normal-link delete-link discontinue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> </a> </p>");
    $(this).closest('.message').append("<p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size'> <a class='normal-link delete-link discontinue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> </a> </p>");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.discontinue', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').html($(this).closest('.message').data("truncated")).append('......').append(" <p class='no-margin text-center x30-font-size drop'> <a class='normal-link success-link continue grey'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> </a> </p>");
    //$(this).find('.drop').css('visibility', 'hidden');

  });
});
```

```css
.drop {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
 }
 
 .message:hover .drop {
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="text-left grey x2-margin-left no-margin-top x2-margin-bottom bolder">
  Some Random Header
</h4>
<p class="message">
  Some Message
</p>
<p class="message">
  Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami ham hock ham, hamburger corned beef short ribs kielbasa biltong t-bone drumstick tri-tip tail sirloin pork chop. Kielbasa turducken turkey cow shoulder pig prosciutto hamburger corned beef short loin, meatloaf tri-tip
  drumstick. Shankle sirloin ground round fatback, cow pancetta boudin t-bone pig. Ham short ribs cow tri-tip ribeye beef ribs boudin. Short ribs pork belly leberkas salami chuck, pork loin ball tip tenderloin turkey chicken pork chop filet mignon biltong.
</p>
<p class="message">
  Disrupt jean shorts viral hella meh, plaid cupidatat magna art party. Echo Park adipisicing literally narwhal. Williamsburg leggings church-key, craft beer forage cornhole jean shorts blue bottle pariatur. Officia sapiente bespoke, locavore plaid cray
  voluptate deep v ex vinyl tote bag chillwave swag occaecat. Sed banh mi 3 wolf moon single-origin coffee quis tempor. Hoodie pitchfork pork belly aliqua, shabby chic elit consequat freegan ethical try-hard mixtape. Schlitz banjo deep v ullamco blog,
  umami nulla sint elit skateboard Godard odio.
</p>
<p class="message">
  Chuck ipsum. Multiple people have died from Chuck Norris giving them the finger. Chuck Norris doesn’t need to swallow when eating food. Crop circles are Chuck Norris' way of telling the world that sometimes corn needs to lie the f*ck down. Chuck Norris
  ordered a Big Mac at Burger King, and got one.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tackled the same issue. In my case, I extended the existing JQuery shave js plugin to add the toggle feature.

```js
// Extends shave.js JQuery plugin with a new shaveWithToggle
// Might be a good idea to put this in it's own file: e.g `jquery.shaveWithToggle.js`
$.fn.shaveWithToggle = function(maxHeight, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  var mergedOptions = $.extend(true, $.fn.shaveWithToggle.defaults, options);

  var shrinkHtml = '<span class="' + mergedOptions.shrinkclassname + '">' + mergedOptions.shrinkhtml + '</span>';
  var expandHtml = '<span class="' + mergedOptions.expandclassname + '">' + mergedOptions.expandhtml + '</span>';
  // Put the expand html as part of the character,
  // so that the shaving would also calculate that
  // as part of the shaving process.
  mergedOptions.character = mergedOptions.character + expandHtml;

  this.shave.call(this, maxHeight, mergedOptions);

  return this.each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var $shaveCharacter = $element.find('.js-shave-char');
    var $shavedContent = $element.find('.' + mergedOptions.classname);

    var $shrinkButton = $(shrinkHtml);
    // Get the expand button element, as it's already added
    // by the shave js as part of the character
    var $expandButton = $shaveCharacter.first('.' + mergedOptions.expandclassname);

    $shaveCharacter.append($expandButton).on('click', function() {
      mergedOptions.expand.call(element, $expandButton, $shaveCharacter, $shrinkButton, $shavedContent);
    });

    $shrinkButton.insertAfter($shavedContent).on('click', function() {
      mergedOptions.shrink.call(element, $shrinkButton, $shaveCharacter, $expandButton, $shavedContent);
    }).hide();
  });
};

$.fn.shaveWithToggle.defaults = {
  // Original shave options, which is used for this plugin
  classname: 'js-shave',
  character: '...',
  // Additional options
  shrinkclassname: 'js-shave-shrink',
  shrinkhtml: ' &lt;&lt;',
  expandclassname: 'js-shave-expand',
  expandhtml: ' &gt;&gt;',
  expand: function($expandButton, $shaveCharacter, $shrinkButton, $shavedContent) {
    $shrinkButton.show();
    $shavedContent.show();
    $shaveCharacter.hide();
  },
  shrink: function($shrinkButton, $shaveCharacter, $expandButton, $shavedContent) {
    $shrinkButton.hide();
    $shavedContent.hide();
    $shaveCharacter.show();
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shave/2.5.3/jquery.shave.min.js" integrity="sha256-vfAHy8DeM92gBftShSriYE5lFMJjHJiqzx9J49ZqFfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="target" style="max-height: 60px; background-color: skyblue;">
  <em>Lorem Ipsum</em> is simply dummy text of the <strong>printing and typesetting industry</strong>. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an <em>unknown printer</em> took a galley of type and scrambled it
  to make a type specimen book. <strong>It has survived not only five centuries</strong>, but also the leap into <strong>electronic typesetting</strong>, remaining essentially unchanged.
  <em>Lorem Ipsum</em> is simply dummy text of the <strong>printing and typesetting industry</strong>. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an <em>unknown printer</em> took a galley of type and scrambled it
  to make a type specimen book. <strong>It has survived not only five centuries</strong>, but also the leap into <strong>electronic typesetting</strong>, remaining essentially unchanged.
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".target").shaveWithToggle(60, {
    // Takes in the normal set of options, plus additional options.
    character: '......',
    classname: 'js-shave-custom',
    spaces: true,
    // The options below are the default values for the additional options from shaveWithToggle plugin
    // Can be ommitted if you're fine with these defaults, or you can change it to whatever
    shrinkclassname: 'js-shave-shrink',
    shrinkhtml: ' &lt;&lt;',
    expandclassname: 'js-shave-expand',
    expandhtml: ' &gt;&gt;',
    expand: function($expandButton, $shaveCharacter, $shrinkButton, $shavedContent) {
      $shrinkButton.show();
      $shavedContent.show();
      $shaveCharacter.hide();
    },
    shrink: function($shrinkButton, $shaveCharacter, $expandButton, $shavedContent) {
      $shrinkButton.hide();
      $shavedContent.hide();
      $shaveCharacter.show();
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any other way i could do this without using the shave plugin?

Comment: There is always another way.
I chose Shave JS since it's fast and so I don't have to re-invent the wheel.